# Hampton Bay 52" Nevali ceiling fan w/hubspace and remote, LED light package flickers or cuts on and off randomly

Tags: lighting, ceiling-fan

I recently installed Hampton Bay 52" Nevali ceiling fans in 5 bedrooms.
The fan has a remote and uses hubspace for smart features.
The light is an LED kit that can dim or adjust color.
The problem I am having in all the fans is when the fan is running and the light is on, the light will randomly flicker or cut off then back on.
This is happening in all 5 fans in all 5 rooms, so I am unsure if it is a fan issue or a power issue in the house.
Original fixture was a 13.7 watt flat LED light. House build was just completed June 2023.

Comment: Assuming the original lights did not have flickering issues and the problem is in all 5 fans, I would lean toward this being a manufacturer issue. Maybe a loose connection in each fan's internal lighting connections?

Comment: They did not, there was no issue with the original LED fixture.

Comment: These fans are only 2 months old. Have you contacted Hampton Bay to ask them about it? Hubspace is a recent Home Depot offering (I had to go look it up) using WiFi and/or Bluetooth for connection. Have you confirmed that your WiFi is stable and that they're not dropping the WiFi connection? (Some of my networking infrastructure is "aged" and I'm having issues with network devices dropping.)

Comment: WiFi is extremely stable, fiber optic broadband. I purchased the fans at the beginning of June and installed them right after we closed on the house. The on and off issue with the light kit was almost immediate when the fans are running

Comment: "The on and off issue with the light kit was almost immediate when the fans are running" When the fan is not running, do the lights flicker?

Comment: turn your AC off, see if the problem stops

Comment: Yeah, they do cut off and on when the fan isn't running, but it tends to be less frequent.

Comment: Yeah have tried it with no AC on, still happens.

Comment: I spoke with their technical support team and they confirmed that there is a bug with Hubspace. If you remove your fan from Hubspace, the flickering should stop. Unfortunately it looks like a software issue.

Comment: I'm new to this specific stack exchange community so I dont have the necessary reputation to post an answer yet, but I had the same issue. Called their warranty department. This is a bug specifically with the receiver in the fan. If you call them and open a ticket, they will send you a new receiver for your fan you can install that resolves this issue. That way you can continue to use the HubSpace app and other smart features.


Hope that helps!

Comment: @TestinginProd I just had to do this same thing. Thank you so much for your answer! Called and they said they would send a new receiver. Came within 4 days. Installed and now it isn’t flickering. The new receiver has an antenna that is supposed to stick out of the housing. Just FYI.